# Django annotate by the objects name which is a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have a code:

```
Data.objects.values("code").annotate(Sum("visits"))
```

And I get the ValuesQS like this:

```
[{'visits__sum': 666, 'code': 4}, {'visits__sum': 15, 'code': 3}, {'visits__sum': 44, 'code': 2}]
```

And it's fine, but the 'code' is a ForeignKey and in my ValuesQS I have a id, but I want to get 'name' of this code. Code model has **str** which retrun the name. How can I get this name in my ValuesQS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the normal double-underscore syntax to follow the FK and get the name field.

```
Data.objects.values("code__name").annotate(Sum("visits"))
```

Comment: Oh, God. It's that simple. Thank you.